# Django-Haystack not returning exact query

Tags: python, json, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm trying to fix my Django-haystack combined with Elasticsearch search results to be exact.

The problem I have now is that when a user try for example, the "Mexico" query, the search results also returns deals in "Melbourne" which is far from being user-friendly.

Anyone can help me to fix this problem?

This is what I've tried so far but no good results:

My forms.py

```
from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm
from haystack.inputs import Exact


class FacetedProductSearchForm(FacetedSearchForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = dict(kwargs.get("data", []))
        self.ptag = data.get('ptags', [])
        self.q_from_data = data.get('q', '')
        super(FacetedProductSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(FacetedProductSearchForm, self).search()

        # Ideally we would tell django-haystack to only apply q to destination
        # ...but we're not sure how to do that, so we'll just re-apply it ourselves here.
        q = self.q_from_data
        sqs = sqs.filter(destination=Exact(q))

        print('should be applying q: {}'.format(q))
        print(sqs)

        if self.ptag:
            print('filtering with tags')
            print(self.ptag)
            sqs = sqs.filter(ptags__in=[Exact(tag) for tag in self.ptag])

        return sqs
```

My search_indexes.py

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from haystack import indexes
from haystack.fields import CharField

from .models import Product


class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(
        document=True, use_template=True,
        template_name='search/indexes/product_text.txt')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    description = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr="description")
    destination = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr="destination") #boost=1.125
    link = indexes.CharField(model_attr="link")
    image = indexes.CharField(model_attr="image")

    # Tags
    ptags = indexes.MultiValueField(model_attr='_ptags', faceted=True)

    # for auto complete
    content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='destination')

    # Spelling suggestions
    suggestions = indexes.FacetCharField()

    def get_model(self):
        return Product

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(timestamp__lte=timezone.now())
```

My models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2047, default='')
    link = models.TextField(max_length=500, default='')

    ptags = TaggableManager()

    image = models.ImageField(max_length=500, default='images/zero-image-found.png')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def _ptags(self):
        return [t.name for t in self.ptags.all()]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product',
                       kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.destination
```

And what I have in my views.py

```
from haystack.generic_views import FacetedSearchView as BaseFacetedSearchView
from .forms import FacetedProductSearchForm

class FacetedSearchView(BaseFacetedSearchView):

    form_class = FacetedProductSearchForm
    facet_fields = ['ptags']
    template_name = 'search_result.html'
    paginate_by = 30
    context_object_name = 'object_list'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution to this problem. Please listen up if you want to avoid loosing any of you reputations by placing a bounty on the same problem.

Basically I had to replace my original `destination` field in my search_indexes.py document to the following line:

From this: `destination = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr="destination")`

To this: `destination = indexes.CharField(model_attr="destination")`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in your use of `dict.get`

```
self.q_from_data = data.get('q', [''])[0]
```

For example

```
data.get('q')  # This will return the string "Mexico"
data.get('q')[0]  # This will return the first letter "M"
```

The line should be

```
self.q_from_data = data.get('q', '')
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @lain, I'm trying this in a sec.

Comment: Am I supposed to run any command after that? Like python manage.py update_index

Comment: You would just need to reload the app

Comment: I still get results in Melbourne

Comment: Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Try calling the `super().__init__` as the first line and your custom code after

Comment: No so sure on what you meant by that, so I updated my question to include an example of what I did, please check.